# How to avoid boilerplate on template arguments when calling parent constructor

Tags: c++, templates, boilerplate, crtp

So let's say I have a class with a lot of template arguments, one of them is the derived class to use CRTP:

```
template <typename Derived, typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
class BaseFoo  {
public:
    BaseFoo(A& a) {}
};
```

And I want to inherit it:

```
class DerivedFoo : public BaseFoo<DerivedFoo, Bc, Cc, Dc, Ec> {
public:
    DerivedFoo(A& a) : BaseFoo<DerivedFoo, Bc, Cc, Dc, Ec>(a) {}
};
```

Is there any trick to avoid all the explicit template argument mentioning?

It is ok if I still have to state `Derived` as template arguments.

Comment: could you use a `typedef`?

Comment: You mean a typedef inside the class? I guess so, but that would be writing the long list of templates twice. `typedef BaseFoo<DerivedFoo, Bc, Cc, Dc, Ec> ParentClass;` you mean this inside DerivedFoo? Because of the need of use the CRTP, I don't know how to make the typedef outside the class.

Comment: Not going to answer because I guess if this were valid then someone would already have mentioned it, but... why are variadic templates not a solution here?

Comment: Well, in fact there are variadic templates before those specific ones, I just omitted them because of seeing it unnecessary for the question. Those have to be there without being variadic anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the derived class' name and lookup the base class name in it if the base class is dependent. If it is not dependent, you can just name the base class unqualified, since it is in scope. No need for all the template arguments

```
class DerivedFoo : public BaseFoo<DerivedFoo, Bc, Cc, Dc, Ec> {
public:
    DerivedFoo(A& a) : BaseFoo(a) {}
};
```

Every class declares its name inside itself. Not only normal classes, but also class template instances. So `BaseFoo` refers to `BaseFoo<...>` in its own scope and the scope of its derived classes.

Comment: Wow, didn't know this was possible. I thought I had to state the whole list of parameters because `BaseFoo<.......>` is like a single class, and `BaseFoo` wasn't statable by its own.

Comment: @alesegdia: Usually and conceptually true (and gosh it's nice to run into an OP who understands that!), but this is an exception for convenience. In fact this is a textbook example of why it's allowed.

Comment: Awesome. It seems I stepped through a textbook example in real life. Thanks for the trick!

Comment: @alesegdia the same underlying feature is used if you write the copy constructor as `DerivedFoo(const DerivedFoo&)`. The template argument list is absent in the parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

First forward declare `DerivedFoo`.

```
class DerivedFoo;
```

then `typedef`

```
typedef BaseFoo<DerivedFoo, Bc, Cc, Dc, Ec> OtherFoo;
```

also possible with `using`

```
using OtherFoo = BaseFoo<DerivedFoo, Bc, Cc, Dc, Ec>;
```

or if you don't care about having to mention `Derived`

```
template <typename Derived>
using OtherFoo = BaseFoo<Derived, Bc, Cc, Dc, Ec>;

class DerivedFoo : public OtherFoo<DerivedFoo> {
    ....
};
```

Comment: Or more modern template alias with using?

Comment: Flawless, that worked. It would be good to have the modern template alias using `using`, as @Alex stated.

Comment: Good, I'll try to figure it out anyway.

Comment: Who cares if it's `typedef X Y;` or `using Y = X;`? It's the same answer either way (+1)

Comment: Sorry but I will change the accepted answer because the simplicity of the other one. Thanks anyway for this trick!